# Matrix Inverses and Limits

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, limits

For what conditions is it true that

$$ \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} S^{-1} = (\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty} S )^{-1} $$
where $S$ is a matrix? Does this happen to work for a $2 \times 2$ matrix? If so, why?

Comment: This worked for me on a couple of sample $2\times 2$ matrices, but I'm not sure how to justify that this always works, or to explain any conditions under which it's true.

Comment: Probably there is the index $n$ missing in the equation.

Comment: Note that $S_n = \left[\begin{smallmatrix} \frac{1}{n} & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ converges to $S = \left[\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ and $S_n^{-1} = \left[\begin{smallmatrix} n & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. Hence, the limit of $S_n^{-1}$ does not exist.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek: OP might well want to consider an "only if" version of the conjecture: suppose that $\lim S_n^{-1}$ does not exist ... then is $\lim S_n$ necessarily non-invertible?  [I know the answer; I'm suggesting that OP might find it instructive to consider this question.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, 
$$
\lim_{x \to a} f(g(x)) = f(\lim_{x \to a} g(x))$$
provided that

1. The inner limit, $\lim_{x \to a} g(x)$, exists and equals, say, $L$, and
2. $f$ is continuous at $L$.

In your example, the function $g$ is the identity ($g(M) = M$) and $f$ is matrix-inversion; Cramer's rule shows that this is a rational function (quotient of polynomials) in the entries of its argument, and hence is continuous wherever the denominator is nonzero. The denominator in Cramer's rule is the determinant, so we can say this:

> If $A_1, A_2, \ldots$ is a sequence of $n \times n$ invertible
>   matrices with a limit matrix $L$ which is invertible,  then  $$
>  \lim_{n \to \infty} (A_n)^{-1} = L^{-1} = \left(\lim_{n \to \infty}
>  A_n\right)^{-1}, $$

just as you'd hoped. It's really just a consequence of the more general theorem on limits that I stated.

Now I was pretty careful in making some assumptions in that higlighted block. You might want to ask yourself "Why did he insist that the matrices $A_i$ all be invertible? Why did he insist that the limit of the $A_i$ exist? Why did he insist that the limit be invertible?" You might try constructing counterexamples when each of these conditions is removed, and when you finish, you'll really understand something solidly.